# Convert a binary string to Hexadecimal and vice-versa in Elixir

Tags: string, binary, elixir, hexdump

How do you convert a binary string to a Hexadecimal String and vice-versa in Elixir?

There are a few posts on SO regarding this topic for other "main stream" languages. There's even an [SO post that benchmarks various C# implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624379/44080)

How do we do this in elixir?

My implementation was too ugly to share... :(

Comment: Even though it's not proper conversion, if the goal is only to take a look at the values in binary form, not to process them further, `inspect("test", base: :hex) == "<<0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74>>"` is also a great option!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I came here wanting to convert between hex strings and **binary data** (not strings). The accepted answer is correct, because strings in Elixir are binaries, but I found it confusing that the answer uses `"foo"` as an example. [`Base.encode16/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Base.html#encode16/2) / [`Base.decode16!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Base.html#decode16!/2) works for all binaries, of which strings are a subset.

Hex to binary:

```
Base.decode16!("0001FEFF")
=> <<0, 1, 254, 255>>
```

Binary to hex:

```
Base.encode16(<<0, 1, 255, 255>>)
=> "0001FFFF"

Base.encode16(<<0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F>>) # equivalent to "foo"
=> "666F6F"

Base.encode16("foo")
=> "666F6F"
```

Answer (score 28):

There is [Base.encode16/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Base.html#encode16/2):

```
iex(1)> Base.encode16("foo")
"666F6F"
```

You can also specify the case:

```
iex(2)> Base.encode16("foo", case: :lower)
"666f6f"
```